# Lightning: why can you not have an expression combined with text in an HTML attribute?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

So, I've been struggling with this for a while, trying to figure out how to get it to work. Here is what I originally did:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary {!v.isLink1 ? 'active' : ''}">
```

And so on. Here's the documentation on it. [Example Expressions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_examples.htm)

However, when you actually try to save this in the developer console, you get the error:

```
Field Integrity Exception: Failed to save undefined: Cannot mix expression and literal string in attribute value, try rewriting like {!'foo' + v.bar}: Source
```

I finally figured out that you have to put all of the classes inside of the expression, like so:

```
<button class="{!v.isLink1 ? 'btn btn-primary active' : 'btn btn-primary'}">
```

This doesn't seem very intuitive. It's also not documented anywhere I could find. Could someone explain to me why it is this way and if it will ever change?

(and hopefully this question saves someone some headaches in the future)

Comment: You could at least make it slightly more efficient with `{!'btn btn-primary' & v.isLink1 ? 'active' : ''}`.

Comment: That's true, good note. That wouldn't make it nearly as bad. It still seems weird to have to do it at all though.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer just in case you don't get anything more satisfactory.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't actually work. See my comment to the answer you posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works this way

```
<button class="{! 'btn btn-primary' + ' ' +  (v.isLink1 ? 'active' : ' ' )}">
```

OR

```
<button class="{! 'btn btn-primary' + ' ' +  if(v.isLink1,'active','')}">
```

the whole attribute value has to be within an expression "{! ...}"
Note that the strings have been concatenated with a + sign.

Answer (score 6):

You could make it slightly more efficient like so:

```
{!'btn btn-primary' & v.isLink1 ? 'active' : ''}
```

As for why that is not allowed, I am also at a loss to explain.

Comment: I'd wager that aura doesn't support it. Other frameworks do, so it's kind of odd, but that's kind of salesforce-y.

Comment: So, I thought this was great. Then I went and actually tried to implement it, but it doesn't work: I get an error that says `Message: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.: Source` So, sorry, this didn't actually help. For reference, I tried removing the spaces around the `&` but it throws a different error. I then tried to change the `&` to a `+` and that doesn't work either.

Comment: As a note, I liked this syntax too so did some digging: this does work if you replace `&` with `&amp;`, although this does reduce the neatness somewhat