# Custom Labels in Lightning Component markup, combined in an expression

Tags: lightning-aura-components

see the next code example:

```
    <lightning:card iconName="custom:custom33" title="{!notequals(v.aType, 'typeA')? 'This is type B' : 'This is type A'}">
      ...
      ...
    </lightning:card>
```

Now I want to use Custom Labels for the string literals 'This is type A' and 'This is the A' but when I want to place them in this expression I got an error:

Cannot mix expression and literal string in attribute value, try rewriting like {!'foo' + v.bar}

How do you do this with custom labels?

Comment: Can you show how exactly you tried? In question

Comment: Your question is duplicate of [Lightning: why can you not have an expression combined with text in an HTML attribute?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70570/lightning-why-can-you-not-have-an-expression-combined-with-text-in-an-html-attr), you should be able to use custom label inside `{!...}` inside merge fields.

Comment: I tried it with using {} on the label. But your solution below works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<lightning:card iconName="custom:custom33" 
title="{!notequals(v.aType, 'typeA')? $Label.c.LabelNameB : $Label.c.LabelNameA}">
 ... ... 
</lightning:card>
```

Change the markup to this